# Why is DMA Continuous Requests not selectable as enable for STM32F446RE?

Tags: stm32, dma, nucleo

I have an Nucleo STM32F446RE and I'm used to enable DMA Continuous Requests with ADC. But in this case, I can only select disable. Why?
If it's not possible to use DMA Continuous Requests with ADC. How can I use my multi-scan ADC?

I can anyway create a DMA Stream and connect it to the ADC inside the DMA tab.

Here is some print screens.

Here I cannot select "Enable"
[image]

But according to data sheet, I can select Enable
[image]
[image]

https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/4d/ed/bc/89/b5/70/40/dc/DM00135183.pdf/files/DM00135183.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00135183.pdf

Should I just change DISBALE to ENABLE here?

```
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T8_TRGO;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 6;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE; // <---- HERE!? 
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

Comment: If you feel that the silly "cube" wizard mismatches the alleged/advertised hardware capability, that is probably something you will have to pursue with ST in order to find out which is in error.

Comment: Is DMA2 Ch0 already in use or not enabled?

Comment: The code you show has `ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE` that doesn't sound right, your screenshot shows it is enabled.

Comment: ADC is one of the peripherals which should be programmed using registers. It would be programmed by you faster quicker than writing this question. Another bonus - you will know what is exactly going on. using HAL  you can only guess or waste time going through its source code

Comment: @P__J__ Acorrding to STM. They recommend using CubeMX instead of registrers.

Comment: @Arsenal no. Have a look again  :)

Comment: @Jeroen3 None of them.

Comment: @ChrisStratton CubeMX invented for a reason. To make it much simpler to set up a project. Everyone is using CubeMX and its hard to find a tutorial about how to use registers only.

Comment: Every attempt ever made to make things "simpler" has ended up making them more limited.  The data manuals describing the registers exist for a reason.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes. But in this case, there must be a bug in the software?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson sorry - but you are a very beginner and already you know what is the correct approach. Good luck

Comment: @P__J__ CubeMX and report bugs to STM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vá para a aba DMA Settings adicione ADC1 a DMA. Após será habilitada a opção Enable DMA.

---

*Google translate says:*

> Go to the DMA Settings tab add ADC1 to DMA. After this the Enable DMA option will be enabled.